# React Native app takes too much memory while profiling

Tags: android, react-native, memory, memory-management, profiler

Recently I use Android Profiler to check memory used for my React Native app. My app is ecommerce app and below is the snapshot of memory when open 10 products (using `push` method of `react-navigation`, so user can go back earlier products). The app take about 900 MB of memory and i don't know if that number is too high compare to another ecommerce app. My question is:

1. What is the optimal RAM used for eccommerce mobile app ? (my app is pretty simple , no video sharing function, no live chat function)
2. Which section among `Others`, `Code`, `Stack`, `Native` and `Java` in Memory tab below reflect the Javascript code ? (So I can improve it)
3. My project also use `react-native-fast-image` to improve loading image. Does that library affect much to the memory used? (I read in here: https://medium.com/free-code-camp/finding-memory-leaks-react-native-app-ios-46e6eeb50c8c)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Other section contains the third party packages memory consumption. Please revisit the packages that you are using and see at which point is peaks.

Native code contains Android elements consumption check for assets like images you are using directly, they get loaded in memory on app launch.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).